# How to make a foreach loop in a while statement efficient in C#

Tags: c#, performance, foreach

I am trying to make the following code a bit more efficient, it works as it should but it takes 12% of processor resources. I have a feeling this can be done more nicely.

this is how my localService looks like:

```
public class localService
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Server { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

This is the function im trying to improve.

```
        while (running)
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<localService> serviceList = Startup.ServiceList;
                foreach (var service in serviceList)
                {
                    using (var sc = new ServiceController(service.ID))
                    {
                        if (sc.Status.ToString() != service.Status)
                        {
                            // Do some work here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }
```

the serviceList contains 4 localService objects at the moment. I have written this in a console app with the intention to make it a windows service.

Comment: Do you think it should take more or less than 12% CPU? What does "more efficient" mean in that context?

Comment: Any specific reasons other than just the feeling that it should take less than 12% resources

Comment: @nvoigt well i think that a fairly simple check for a string shouldn't use 12% cpu. since this will be the only thing this litte app does.

V4Vendetta: nope, its just a feeling (and a lack of knowledge)

Comment: Have you tried Visual Studios Performance profiler? It could perhaps point you in the direction of your prolem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need it to run as fast as possible, you could add a `Thread.Sleep(ms);` in at the end of the loop.  It causes your program to do nothing for roughly the number of milliseconds you pass in.

```
Thread.Sleep(250);
```

would cause the loop to run about 4 times a second if it doesn't take long to execute.

Comment: i see how this can improve but im trying to obtain real-time information if a status changes. However, if i cant find anything better, this will be my fallback. Better near real-time than a slow performing app.

Comment: I did some further testing with this. Putting in Thread.Sleep(100); made reduced the cpu usage to 0 - 1%. This works like a charm. Just out of curiosity: why is it, that it makes this kind of improvement?

Comment: @Donniewiko Without knowing what you have in the loop, there isn't a lot anyone can suggest.  If you don't want to thrash the processor, you can add a sleep.  If you want to know how to make your code more efficient, use a profiler to tell you how long each part of the code is executing.  If the ServiceController constructor is taking the longest you could precreate and cache them, for example.

Comment: @Donniewiko Without the sleep, regardless of how long your code takes, it will run until it hits a limit.  If it isn't bound by disk or network I/O, it might run as often as your RAM or processor will allow, consuming a lot of processor time.  The sleep just limits the rate.